# PhoneGap plugin for handling missed calls

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I am searching for PhoneGap plugin to allow handling incoming call states, such as `RINGING` and `IDLE` states on Android. I have searched the official repository of plugins here:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins

and have also searched on Google but no good.

I also wonder, if the same concept is at all possible on iOS? As far as I know, it's not available on iOS.

Comment: iOS not allow to call detail and sms detail access and it is possible only in jailbreak device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this plugin for Android:

https://github.com/madeinstefano/PhoneStateChangeListener

For iOS, as mentioned by Ved, it does not allow you to retrieve call and SMS details besides phone state.